# HowTo: Combine values from two arrays with the same keys in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of months => values, like so...

```
$months = array(
  'January'   => 0.00,
  'February'  => 0.00,
  'March'     => 0.00,
  'April'     => 0.00,
  'May'       => 0.00,
  'June'      => 0.00,
  'July'      => 0.00, 
  'August'    => 0.00,
  'September' => 0.00,
  'October'   => 0.00,
  'November'  => 0.00,
  'December'  => 0.00,
)
```

which I would like to combine with values from a temp array...

```
$temp = array(
  'February'  => 200.00,
  'May'       => 17.50,
)
```

Such that I am left with the following...

```
$months = array(
  'January'   => 0.00,
  'February'  => 200.00, // Combined
  'March'     => 0.00,
  'April'     => 0.00,
  'May'       => 17.50,  // Combined
  'June'      => 0.00,
  'July'      => 0.00, 
  'August'    => 0.00,
  'September' => 0.00,
  'October'   => 0.00,
  'November'  => 0.00,
  'December'  => 0.00,
)
```

Comment: What programming language is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php)

```
$result = array_replace($months, $temp);
print_r($result);
```

Gives...

```
Array
(
    [January] => 0
    [February] => 200
    [March] => 0
    [April] => 0
    [May] => 17.5
    [June] => 0
    [July] => 0
    [August] => 0
    [September] => 0
    [October] => 0
    [November] => 0
    [December] => 0
)
```

Comment: Just a question : is it working if `February` is 50 and so I want 50 + 200 = 250?

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is a foreach :

```
foreach ($months as $month => $value) {
    // I check if the $temp array has the $month as key too
    if (key_exists($month, $temp)) {
        // I combine the $temp array value with the $months array value for the $month key
        $months[$month] += $temp[$month];
    }
}
```

Output with a `var_dump($months)` after the loop:

```
array (size=12)
  'January' => float 0
  'February' => float 200
  'March' => float 0
  'April' => float 0
  'May' => float 17.5
  'June' => float 0
  'July' => float 0
  'August' => float 0
  'September' => float 0
  'October' => float 0
  'November' => float 0
  'December' => float 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can result by using array_merge

```
$months = array(
  'January'   => 0.00,
  'February'  => 0.00,
  'March'     => 0.00,
  'April'     => 0.00,
  'May'       => 0.00,
  'June'      => 0.00,
  'July'      => 0.00, 
  'August'    => 0.00,
  'September' => 0.00,
  'October'   => 0.00,
  'November'  => 0.00,
  'December'  => 0.00,
);
$temp = array(
  'February'  => 200.00,
  'May'       => 17.50,
);

$result  = array_merge($months, $temp);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
exit;
```